# How to save image coming from multer memory disk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, multipartform-data, multer

I use multer in nodejs to handle multipart/formdata request and get the image file on the request like this :

```
import multer from "multer";

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: { fileSize: 1000000000, files: 2 },
});



app.post("/", upload.single("image"), (req, res , next) => {
      const imageFile = req.file

      dbx
        .filesUpload({ path: "/image.png", contents: imageFile })
        .then((response: any) => {
         
        })
        .catch((uploadErr) => {
         
        });
    }
  )
```

The problem is I can't upload the image and it gives me error that it's a Buffer not an actual image . How can I generate the image from `req.file` then upload it without saving it on the disk ?

Comment: It gives an error that *what* is a Buffer and not an actual image?

Comment: you can access buffer by `req.file.buffer`, so try `const imageFile = req.file.buffer`.

Comment: @user3840170 Yes it only accepts image files like   wallpaper.png wallpaper.jpg  so I want to convert req.file image to an actual image inside my controller and send it to dropbox api without saving the req.file inside the server as a file .

Comment: @turivishal I can access it but I want to convert it to an actual image file and send to dropbox api .

Comment: ‘Yes’ is not an answer to a ‘what’ question. Go figure.

Comment: @user3840170 How can I generate the image from req.file then upload it without saving it on the disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by sending the file buffer itself to dropbox like this

```
    const imageFile = req.file && req.file.buffer;

    dbx
      .filesUpload({ path: "/life.png", contents: imageFile })
      .then((response: any) => {
        console.log("SUccess");
      })
      .catch((uploadErr) => {
        console.log("ERRRR");
        console.log(uploadErr);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode your data or change it's encoding but to convert it to an image doesn't make any sense.

The example code provided by dropbox [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/main/examples/typescript/node/upload.js), reads a file  in`utf-8` and uploads it.

You can also do that same by taking the buffer and uploading it.

```js
  const imageFile = req.file.buffer;
```

Comment: I did try that but dropbox won't recognize and preview the image file . Issue link here https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/1000

Comment: Just to be clear, have you have tried setting imageFile to req.file.buffer?

Comment: I solved the issue by sending the buffer image itself

Comment: Great! i've update my answer i also what to note that this is what @turivishal was telling you in the comments